# How can I package a runnable jar file with Maven (JDK11 and JavaFX project)

Tags: java, maven, javafx

How can I package runnable jar file from a JDK11 based Maven project using JavaFX?

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hu.infokristaly</groupId>
    <artifactId>JPasswordProtectorJDK11</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>hu.infokristaly.jpasswordprotector.JPasswordProtector</mainClass>
                    <options>
                        <option>--add-exports</option>
                        <option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls</option>
                    </options>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                                <option>--add-exports</option>
                                <option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I try use ControlsFX within my project. So I must add --add-exports option in execute section. I tryed maven-assembly-plugin but Java missed JavaFX libraries when I run the packaged jar file. I'd like to run the project with java -jar JPasswordProtector.jar command. Please help.

Comment: have a look at the javafx tag wiki: it has a whole section about deploying fx applications :)

Comment: I tryed 3 solution, but neither can help me.

Comment: *"How can I package runnable jar file from a JDK11 based Maven project using JavaFX?"* There's basically no supported way to do that. If you have tried one of the supported methods described in the tag wiki (or elsewhere) to create an application bundle (e.g. using `jpackage`), edit your question to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I used the maven-shade-plugin

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>hu.infokristaly.jpasswordprotector.SuperMain</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The SuperMain contains simple main method to start JavaFX Applicatoin.

```
package hu.infokristaly.jpasswordprotector;

public class SuperMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPasswordProtector.main(args);
    }
}
```

I don't want to use jlink for a small program.

```
mvn clean javafx:jlink
```

This made a a 433MB image, and I want use small native-image from graalvm.